# For all the products or For all products

Tags: grammar

I have an eCommerce website which has variants of products like for  eg.

Shirt - Green and small, 
        Red and medium,

After selecting the color and  size, the user is required to fill in the quantity for each variant he is willing to purchase.

What should the help message read?

*"Please enter quantity for all the product variants"*

OR

*"Please enter quantity for all product variants"*

Answer (score 4):

Why not go for the simpler, clearer option here:

> Please enter the quantity for **each** variant selected

Thereby removing the ambiguity/confusion caused by using "all".